# org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException JSP and JSTL query

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee-6

I need help . I am using Java DB, the integrated server with netbeans
but  when I try to use a JSTL query inside from the jsp page a error is triggered. I am reading a book but I can't execute the code on my pc. I believe I have problem with the configuration of my database server

Error

```
    HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: 
            SELECT name, city, state FROM customer
        : La tabla/vista 'CUSTOMER' no existe.
root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: La tabla/vista 'CUSTOMER' no existe.
root cause

org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: La tabla/vista 'CUSTOMER' no existe.
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/sample</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
    <%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Aug 28, 2010, 7:52:34 PM
    Author     : heffel
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
        <sql:query var="allRows" dataSource="jdbc/sample">
            SELECT name, city, state FROM customer
        </sql:query>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="currentRow"
                       items="${allRows.rows}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${currentRow.name}</td>
                    <td>${currentRow.city},
                        ${currentRow.state}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you calling this query: `select * from PRODUCT;`
It seems it's not in your `index.jsp` page.

Comment: Sorry. I correct the code but the program continue showing this error

Comment: the error is pretty self descriptive, do you really have the table `customer` in your schema? Have you configured your `DataSource` connections pool correctly?

Comment: How can I do this? I am begginer

Comment: if you are using Tomcat as application server, you should read this article: [JNDI Resources HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html)

Comment: I am using glassfish 4

Comment: which database are you using? have you created the tables you want to select values? without these basics knowledge you will not go anywhere. Google is a good place to start with.

Comment: ok the database is derby

Comment: Your database does not have any table called 'customer', or at least Derby is not able to find it. Check with the `ij` tool command `show tables` if it exists. If it does, check [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggndx.html), it may help you to configure your `DataSource`. In Ubuntu `ij` is available installing package `derby-tools`, but it is likely to be included in your Glassfish distribution already. You can see a quick intro [here](http://zetcode.com/db/apachederbytutorial/ij/).